# Diagnostics feature in Angular 2 vs React

Tags: reactjs, angular, react-native

When an Mobile application crashes, we would like to gather diagnostics information from the user device and mobile app on why and when/what step the app would have crashed.

Which of these frameworks Angular2 vs React+Libraries have better diagnostics capabilities ?

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate with Fabric that's is made by Twitter. After integration, you will have access to Crashlytics which reports each critical crash on their dashboard: https://fabric.io/home with the information you need.

You can also log additional information from your js code with use of their API.